# Get data from one input box to another input on another page via anchors

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I have a search input box on an index page and I want it to redirect to a search page and automatically fill in the search box with the text in the input box and then trigger the .keyUp() event manually. 
 I am a total beginner at javascript and html so please excuse my poor coding.
This is my current code for my index.html page:

```
<div class="address-bar">
    <input id="search-text" type="text">
    <button id="search-enter">Search</button>
</div>
```

And my javascript for that page is is:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var searchquery = $("#search-text")
    $("#search-enter").click(redirect)
    function redirect() {
        window.location("http://<example>.com/search.html#q=" + searchquery + "E")
    }
</script>
```

I am currently using [Matt york's fuzzy search libary](https://github.com/mattyork/fuzzy/blob/master/README.md).
And my code on my other page is:

```
<h1>Search:</h1>
<input type="text" id="search" class="search"></input>
<div id="characters">
</div>
```

With the javascript:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script>
var anchor = window.location.hash()
var question = anchor.substring(3, -1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.search').val(question);
$('.search').keyup();
```

That said you might want to give an id to the input element.

Comment: There is an Id for both input elements.